# Azure cosmosdb changefeed for document collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to register a service running on a cluster node as observer to changefeed for a document collection across multiple cosmos db accounts in th cluster?

In the case of an Azure Function(triggered by ChangeFeed of a document collection), the function needs to be provisioned for each cosmos db account in the cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database

How can a service API endpoint be triggered by changefeed processor library?
Or, how can a service running on a cluster node be registered as an observer to changefeed for a document collection across multiple cosmos db accounts in the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Feed Processor Library can be used within any console/worker application and running within any host that is able to have your application running. Samples are available on the GitHub repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet#example

The limitation is that one observer can listen to one collection in one account. If you have multiple accounts, each collection (even if they have the same name) is a different collection and requires an individual instance of the Change Feed Processor Library running (collections do not span multiple accounts). This instance could be in the same compute unit as the rest, and it will share the resources (CPU/RAM) or in an independent one.

Comment: Can you please share more information on whether an azure function with trigger on the collection be a better option here or a console/worker application registered as an observer for the change feed a better option?

Comment: They are both valid. It depends on the level of abstraction you prefer. With Azure Functions, you pay per # of executions (on Consumption Plan) and the scaling can be handled for you, you dont code observers and thus, injecting dependencies could be harder, but overall coding is much simpler. With CFP Library you need a worker which you pay, regardless of # of changes, you have more control on the internal code and can customize scaling to your liking, but you are also responsible for maintaining those workers.

Comment: I am trying to use CFP library with a worker and an observer registered. My lease collection gets updated whenever there is a change in the monitored collection. But ProcessChangesAsync method is not getting invoked. I am running the worker service locally from my machine.

Comment: Check if the `Owner` that appears in the leases has the same name as the HostName you using in your worker. If not, that means you have another observer running that is listening for the same collection using the same leases collection. If you want to have multiple independent workers listening to the same collection and using the same leases collection, assign a [`LeasePrefix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.changefeedprocessor.changefeedprocessoroptions.leaseprefix?view=azure-dotnet) to each worker group.

Comment: Owner is null. I have only one instance of the worker running that too locally.

Comment: Owner = null means noone is picking up that lease. Is your worker running or is it starting the processor (StartAsync) and exiting? After StartAsync you might want to lock the worker and keep it running until you call StopAsync to end it.

Comment: If this worker needs to be deployed for multiple cosmos db accounts, how can this closeAsync be invoked for each worker service instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191560/discussion-between-vanathi-and-matias-quaranta).